# How to add a value to a asp:BoundField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following `GridView` which displays the `File Name` and a `Download` button and `View in Browser` button:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText = "No PDF was generated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Date" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClick="DownloadFile" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Text="View in Browser" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='blank';" runat="server" OnClick="ViewFile" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I am modifying the `File Name` from C# using this:

```
files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
```

I want to be able to add the file modified date to the `File Date` column for each file, so I tried to use the following line:

```
files.Add(new ListItem(File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(Path.GetFileName(filePath)).toString(), filePath));
```

But that adds another row below each file name and also displays the wrong date.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix my code so each `file name` column corresponds to the file's modified date in the `file date` column?

Full code:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\PDFGenerate");
                List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                    files.Add(new ListItem(File.GetLastWriteTime(Path.GetFileName(filePath)).ToString(), filePath));

                }
                GridView1.DataSource = files;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ce)
            {
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(files.Count() + ""); // displays the count for the files being displayed
        }
```

Comment: What does `files` variable stand for? Is it the data source? Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: @Dethariel Thank you for reminding me... I added the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this might work:

Change the `asp:BoundField` for the "File Date" column to this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="File Date" />
```

And your `foreach` to something like this:

```
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
   files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), File.GetLastWriteTime(Path.GetFileName(filePath)).ToString()));
}
```

`ListItem` has "Text" and "Value" properties which I think get mapped to you `asp:BoundField`'s `DataField` attribute. Then in the `foreach` just add 1 entry per file and populate the "Text" and "Value" fields respectively.

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a charm but I am still not getting the correct value for the `GetLastWriteTime` function. I am seeing the following: `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM` for all of them

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge That is a matter of another question, I think

Comment: Thank you. I will open another question

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge see if you have better luck with `File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath)`, it may need the whole path and not just the file name